# How to smooth noisy vector field for quiver plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data set that I want to plot as a quiver plot. The set contains parameters of stars represented as ellipses (center, long axis length, short axis length, bearing (angle) of the long axis) that I want to draw as a vector field with quiver plot. The data (axis lengths and bearings) is noisy and I need to smooth it. While smoothing works fine for axis length I'm stuck with angle smoothing. The problem here is that any ellipse is visually (and for my purposes too) equivalent to an ellipse rotated by 180 degrees and ellipses' angles are distributed in the range from 0 to 180. Smoothing for the most part of this range works fine except for corner cases where angles are close to 0 and close to 180. While two ellipses with angles close to 0 and close to 180 looks visually similar, their "average" has an angle of 90 degrees which is clearly wrong.  See an example of unsmoothed data (white stars and green arrows representing these stars) where the smoothing breaks. To be clear I don't need the direction of the arrow, and in my final plot I'm hiding arrow heads. I need only the angle/bearing of it and the average of two angles of 179.9 and 0.1 needs to be either 180 or 0 but not 90.
Any idea how to approach the problem? [image: part of quiver plot that shows corner case]

Comment: I would triangulate the data and use a wavefront propagation to choose the "best" representation modulo 180. If you can share a dataset, I will try to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

First, you can convert your angle to an int and expand it to the full range of that int and take advantage of overflow.  For example:

```
np.astype((ang-180.)/360.*65536, 'uint16')
```

This may work if your smoothing function is simple and doesn't have comparison operators in it and is in my opinion a nasty hack.

Second, rotate your angle by some arbitrary amount, and do the smoothing multiple times, picking the best answer.

I would smooth the original, then rotate by 120, smooth that, rotate by 240, smooth that.  Then un-rotate and then keep only the angles that agree.  Of course this comes with a 3x+ performance hit.

Edit:
Third option:  Smooth the vector components.

Comment: Thanks Paul, the first one is out because the smoothing is done with local regression and it won't work. I think the second one can work if I rotate angles three times by something like 15degrees, rotate them back and take median. Still the method is kind of not very elegant. I was also thinking about the third method. But the problem is similar, vectors (0.999,0) and (-0.999,0) while having the same direction (for my purposes) will average to (0,0)

Comment: If you want elegance, you'll probably have to tinker with the smoothing algorithm.  Here is some discussion on how to compare cyclic numbers: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/6grSponecHw  It would be kind of nice if numpy had a datatype that was "cyclic" and overrode `__add__`, `__sub__`, etc... to always give the desired angular result.  Must be some reason it hasn't been done..  I've run into this problem with angles numerous times and have always had to `var[var>180]-=180` my way out of it.